# is there a resource (prepared statement) leak here in this code?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, prepared-statement

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
    if (ps != null) {
        ps = doSomething(ps);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
} finally {
    if (ps!=null) {
        ps.close();
    }
}

private PreparedStatement doSomething(PreparedStatement ps) {
    ps.setString(1, "test");
}
```

"execute update is only called once". String "sql" is different under different conditions and will have different number of bind variables, method doSomething has different implementations in subclasses for setting the bind variables.

Eclipse complains this as a potential leak because of re-assigning prepared statement. Is there a resource leak here?

Comment: (1) Consider try-with-resources. (2) Why does `doSomething` need to *return* the statement instead of just modifying it as shown in this example?

Comment: It's because doSomething is overriden to do different things in different subclasses.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. What does it do that couldn't be `void`?

Comment: Where are you closing the connection returned from `getConnection()`?

Comment: Different implementations set different number of parameters for a different flavors of sql string. For example, one of the implementation sets two parameters, another one sets one etc.

Comment: @dnault: Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What Eclipse and @chrylis and @ jakub-kaszycki are trying to tell you is that the line`ps = doSomething(ps);` should probably be just `doSomething(ps);`

Comment: Gotcha! That explains it. Thanks all.

Answer (score -1):

In the line:

```
ps = doSomething(ps);
```

The original value of `ps` **might** be dropped, depending on whether it is kept by `doSomething`.

Anyways, Java keeps everything under garbage collector, so there is nothing like "memory leak". Call it dropping or loss.

Comment: You absolutely can have a memory leak, for example with a runaway cache, and Java can leak resources such as database connections.

Comment: @chrylis OK, natives are other thing, I meant pure Java without Sun's internals nor native streams

Comment: JDBC connections *are* pure Java.

Comment: But which memory is not freed

Comment: Memory leak is a non-freed memory after the program finishes. Resource leak is dropping a stream

Comment: Assuming that the getConnection() is assigned to a connection object and by closing an open connection in the finally block, since there is nothing but setting parameters in doSomething(ps), I don't see there is a leaking preparedStatement. Agreed? In simple terms, passing a statement object as an argument, set parameters like it is done above and returning it does not result in a resource leak. Is that true?